# Strange behavior with Ruby's %w shortcut

Tags: ruby

This works as I expect, returning `true`:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].include? 'e'
```

This also works as I expect, also returning `true`:

```
x = %w('a b c d e')
x.include? 'e' # => true
```

But this does not work as I expect, returning `false`:

```
%w('a b c d e').include? 'e'
```

The strangest part of it is that either the first or last value returns `false`, while the interior values return `true`. I have tried this with strings of from three to five characters, with the same result.

Why?

Edit: iGian asked me to check whether `x.include? 'e'` really evaluated to `true`. It doesn't. I see now when I tried that case I didn't put the characters in quotes! I think I need to increase my screen font size or get new glasses. So, the values in `%w ('a b c')` are `'a`, `b` and `c'`. Which explains perfectly why I get the behavior I find.

Comment: Please, check: for me `p x.include? 'e' # => false`. Isn't it?

Comment: @iGian Yes, it is! See my edit, and thanks. Looks like the absent-minded-professor gene bit me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is pretty obvious if you drop this into `irb` and see what Ruby thinks:

```
%w('a b c d e')
# => ["'a", "b", "c", "d", "e'"]
```

It doesn't contain `e`, but instead `e'` because you're using `%w` incorrectly.

Remove quotes when using `%w`. It splits on spaces, not quotes. Any non-space characters are considered to be part of the string and get "stuck" on to their neighbouring letters.

Comment: Obvious when you know. I was understanding the `%w` shortcut to accept a string argument which it then split on spaces, like `split.('a b c d e')`. Thank you from a "Ruby newbie." :)

Comment: It's roughly equivalent to `"'a b c d e'".strip.split(/\s+/)`, but arguably a lot more concise. There's also the `%i[...]` equivalent which instead of strings returns symbols.

Comment: All good to know. Thank you! Yeah, I dropped it into `irb` but I didn't notice those extra quotes. I'll have to increase the size of my terminal font. Not to mention pay more attention to that.